# With telethon is it possible to forward a message to a group topic?

Tags: python, telethon

There is nothing in the documentation about forwarding or sending messages to topic.

I have tried using `client.forward_messages` but, since there's nothing in the documentation about topics, I was left flailing and guessing what might work. E.g.:

```
await client.send_message(
    destination__id,
    message,
    reply_to=destination_topic_id,
)
```

```
    if (0x10000 <= ord(x) <= 0x10FFFF) else x for x in text
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The friendly `client.forward_messages` method does not yet expose a way to forward messages to a specific topic. However, you can use [`ForwardMessagesRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/forward_messages.html) directly like so:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions

client = TelegramClient(...)

client(functions.messages.ForwardMessagesRequest(
    from_peer=source_chat,     # <- chat where the messages exist
    id=[123, 456],             # <- message ids to forward from source_chat
    to_peer=destination_chat,  # <- where to forward the messages
    top_msg_id=topic_id,       # <- topic id
))
```

Comment: Thanks you for this. Somehow I thought top was about position or something.

Comment: The name is confusing. But topics are essentially messages that reply to a special service message as far as I'm aware.